# Как правильно нарисовать линию линейной регрессии? От края до края плоскости или от первой точки до последней?

Tags: математика

Правильно будет рисовать так?

[image: Линейная регрессия от точки до точки]

Или так?

[image: Линейная регрессия от края до края]

Comment: Правильно будет посчитать по формуле Метода Наименьших Квадратов и нарисовать так, как получится по этой формуле.

Comment: @pepsicoca1а если мне нужно продлить линию с первого скрина до правого и левого краев что для этого нужно? как считать?

Comment: Обычно используется как на 1 скрине, `-x, +x`, `-y, +y`, а то, как будет нарисован отрезок, зависит от выбранных точек `x` и `y`.

Comment: Ваша задача определить, какие "края" правильнее? Однозначного ответа на этот вопрос нет. Или как отсечь прямую по координатам "краёв"?

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про МНК например здесь для начала:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

В Вашем случае модель, очевидно, линейная. Получите систему из двух линейных уравнений, решите эту систему и построите свою прямую линейной регрессии.

А если в Википедии слишком сложно, то поищите в других местах. В сети полно объяснений что такое МНК.